# How to get ADB logs using eggPlant automation tool

Tags: android, automation, adb, eggplant

Can anyone tell me how can we get adb logs using eggPlant automation tool.Actually i want to have adb logs for my device when running eggPlant scripts.

Please help me out in this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the previous answer is incorrect as [adb command support does exist in eggPlant](http://docs.testplant.com/?q=content/adb-command-support). There *are* ways to get adb logs in eggPlant. Here's how:

- `adb logcat` is the command that enables getting adb logs. (Warning: This will print a ton of info!)
- You need a way to execute `adb logcat` within eggPlant. This is accomplished using [the `shell` command](http://docs.testplant.com/?q=content/system-interaction)
- On some systems (I am using eggPlant for Windows) you need to dump the output of the `shell` command to a file and then *read the file back into a variable*.

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is no such command or something else.eggPlant identifies only object or script to execute the command.